# Almacenar el resultado de una consulta de SQL en VBS - problemas

Tags: sql, vbs

Buenas comunidad de StackOverflow. Ojala podáis ayudarme.

Tengo por un lado un consulta de SQL que me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este query es ejecutado desde un script en VBS tal que así, y obteniendo el siguiente fallo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que el fallo se debe a que no encuentra/no existe el valor solicitado.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Quisiera poder obtener el resultado de mi consulta en VBS para almacenarla en un array.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Y si pones `Select SysNo from ...`, es decir sin paréntesis ¿te funciona?

Comment: Has probado a acceder a la colección de resultados por el índice. Rst.Fields.Item(0). Aunque si no accedes por el nombre, yo le quitaría los paréntesis, como te han indicado.

Comment: y de paso poner como ejecutas tu consulta, y tu lectura, me queda la duda si es ahí el error.

Comment: Te aconsejaría que primero armes el query en una variable y después copies el resultado de esa variable en sql e intentes correrlo, ahi te darás cuenta cual es el error probablemente algún símbolo que estas colocando demás

Comment: Gracias Chicos! finalmente ha funcionado... usando  "Rst.Fields.Item(0)" . No estoy muy  experimentado y esto, que sera cosas faciles para vosotros, a mi me ha supuesto un mundo!!!